# Edit a message in a specific channel in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

(Discord.py)

I'm trying to make a "Status" message in a dedicated channel, this message will be affected by messages sent in other channels
For this I need to select my message in said channel and then edit it

I've been looking around and trying stuff for about an hour now but I can't find anything that works, the closest I got is this:

```
status_msg = "Placeholder"
status_channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
status_message = status_channel.fetch_message(messageID)
await status_message.edit(content=status_msg)
```

With the error: `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'`

I believe I need a different editting command?

( I'm using `@client.event` and this needs to happen in `async def on_message(message):` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the `fetch_message` function based on the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message).

```py
status_msg = "Placeholder"
status_channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
status_message = await status_channel.fetch_message(messageID)
await status_message.edit(content=status_msg)
```